# Migrating Ruby on Rails application to Docker: Issues with Docker-Compose

Tags: postgresql, docker, docker-compose

I'm new to creating my own docker images. I've been following along with this [guide](https://blog.cloud66.com/migrating-a-rails-application-to-docker/). I've successfully built my by using `docker-compose build` in the root directory.

However, I encounter the same issue every time I try to run: `docker-compose up`

I get the following error:

```
Pulling postgresql (postgresql:latest)...
ERROR: pull access denied for postgresql, repository does not exist or may require 'docker login'
```

I've setup a docker account. I can run a postgresql image using the [documentation](https://hub.docker.com/_/postgres/).

I'm at a loss as to what to do. I'm thinking I should modify my Dockerfile for my project or the docker-compose.yml file, but I'm unsure.

Also, when I build my app, I get the following at the beginning:

```
postgresql uses an image, skipping
```

My docker-compose.yml file looks like:

```
web:
    build: .
    command: rails s -e production
    ports:
      - 3000 
    links:
      - postgresql
      - postgresql:postgresql.cloud66.local
    environment:
      - RAILS_ENV=production
      - RACK_ENV=production
    postgresql:
    image: postgresql
```

Comment: Have you logged into docker before pulling from the private repo?

Comment: If so try adding --allow-insecure-ssl to the end of your docker-compose up

Comment: https://github.com/docker/compose/issues/1622

Comment: The official PostgreSQL image is just named [postgres](https://hub.docker.com/_/postgres).

Answer (score 0):

You may be running an outdated version of docker-compose.0

Also, your YAML seems to have an indentation error:

```
web:
    build: .
    links:
      - postgresql
    postgresql:
    image: postgresql
```

This should be:

```
web:
  build: .
  links:
    - postgresql
postgresql:
  image: postgresql
```

Maybe it was just a copy & paste error, because the error message implies it was parsed correctly.